# What is spine strictness

Tags: haskell, data-structures, lazy-evaluation, strictness

In Haskell, the term *spine strictness* is often mentioned in relation to lazy evaluation. Though I have a vague understanding of that it means, it would be nice to have a more *concrete* explanation about:

- What is the *spine* of a data structure
- What does *spine strictness* mean?
- What are the *benefits* when comparing spine strict data structures with lazy ones?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's an example

```
> length (undefined : 3 : 4 : undefined : [])
4
> length (2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : undefined)
<<loop>>
```

The first list contains bottoms as elements, but the "shape" of the list is fully defined. Roughly speaking, every list cell has a clearly defined "pointer" to its next element. This "shape" is called the spine.

The second list, by comparison, has completely defined elements, yet its spine is not defined. This is because it does not end with the empty list `[]`, but with a non-terminating expression `undefined`. In this case the spine is not defined.

The function `length` cares about the spine, not the elements. So it is able to work in the first case (thanks to laziness), but not the second. We say that `length` is strict in the spine, but not in the elements of the list.

Similarly, in tree data structures, the spine is the "shape" of the tree. Some functions such as tree height can be written without inspecting elements, but only the spine. Such functions are strict in the spine.

While some functions have to be spine-strict (e.g. length), others can be written both in a spine-strict or spine-lazy fashion. For instance `map` on lists is spine-lazy: it will return the first element of the output before accessing all the spine of its input. A stricter variant can be obtained by

```
map' :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]
map' _ []     = []
map' f (x:xs) = (f x :) $! map' f xs
```

Whether this is beneficial depends on the context. Consider

```
-- apply n times function f
iter n f = foldr (.) id $ replicate n f

list1 = iter 1000 (map  succ) [1..10]
list2 = iter 1000 (map' succ) [1..10]
```

If I demand `head list1` I will force the application of the 1000 maps only at the first element of the list. This means that after that there will be 1000 allocated thunks in memory holding up space.

Instead, `head list2` will force the application of the 1000 maps on the whole list. So, all the 1000 thunks can be immediately garbage collected, reclaiming memory.

Comment: in the first example however, `length (2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : undefined)` will not loop but give an exception immediately because undefined in haskell is not a 'not terminating expression' though I get what you mean, but showing it in repl style makes it confusing

Comment: @Markus1189: If you're still wondering why it's called *spine*, try the following in GHCi: `let x = map (+1) [1..10]`, `length x`, `:sprint x`. Then you will clearly see the spine of the list

Comment: @Zeta Thanks for pointing out the sprint command! Very useful! One quick question I have though is why `let x = "foo"` `:sp x` gives me `x = _` but `let x = ['f', 'o', 'o']` `:sp x` gives me `x = "foo"`

Comment: @semicolon Interesting. I believe GHC(i) may be playing some optimization here. Instead of allocating the list-of-chars immediately, the string might be stored in a more compact form which is not unfolded until the string is really demanded. This is just a guess, though.

Comment: @semicolon: chi is right. Use `:set -ddump-simpl -ddump-ds` to see more. `"foo"` is a `CString`, whereas `['f','o','o']` is already a list and evaluated at that point. By the way, it's better to [ask such questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), since comment notifications might not get noticed.